# Spotify Web API - Error 400 with no body on playlist creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, spotify

I am trying to create and populate a playlist using the Spotify Web API. I am following [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/) official reference, and I am using Python 3 with the requests module. Here is my code:

```
def spotify_write_playlist(auth, name, tracks, public=True):
    ids = []
    for track in tracks:
        track_id = track.services['spotify']
        if track_id: ids.append(track_id)
    headers = {
        "authorization":"Bearer " + auth.token,
        "content-type":"application/json"
    }
    data = {
        "name":name,
        "public":public
    }
    r = makeRequest("https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" + auth.username + "/playlists", "post", 201, json=data, headers=headers)
    playlist_id = json.loads(r.content)['id']
    data = {"uris":ids}
    r = makeRequest("https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" + auth.username + "/playlists/" + playlist_id + "/tracks", "post", 201, json=data, headers=headers)
    return playlist_id

def makeRequest(url, method="get", expectedCode=200, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        r = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
        if r.status_code == 429:
            time.sleep(TMR_DELAY)
            continue
        elif r.status_code == expectedCode:
            return r
        else:
            if "spotify.com" in url:
                raise spotify.ApiError(r.status_code, expectedCode, r.content)
            else:
                raise youtube.ApiError(r.status_code, expectedCode, r.content)
```

The makeRequest function is a wrapper around requests.request that handles ratelimiting.

The above code when run with a bunch of sample tracks returns an error 400 at the first call of makeRequest, so my sample tracks can't be the issue as only the name and public variables are involved with that call.

The error response has no body, so no description of the error. This suggests I am probably missing something very obvious. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playlist creation request stopped erroring, and I have no idea why. I must of changed whatever was wrong when trying to diagnose the problem. I thought it was trying to create a playlist of the same name but spotify allows duplicate playlists. Maybe something was wrong with the token or token object I was using. Sorry.

However, I also found another issue when the previous one was cleared: the when adding to tracks you specify the track uri (spotify:track:abcdef123) not just the track id (abcdef123). I have revised spotify_write_playlists below:

```
def spotify_write_playlist(auth, name, tracks, public=True):
ids = []
for track in tracks:
    track_id = track.services['spotify']
    if track_id: ids.append("spotify:track:"+track_id)
headers = {
    "authorization":"Bearer " + auth.token,
    "content-type":"application/json"
}
data = {
    "name":name,
    "public":public
}
r = makeRequest("https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" + auth.username + "/playlists", "post", 201, json=data, headers=headers)
playlist_id = json.loads(r.content)['id']
data = {"uris":ids}
r = makeRequest("https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/" + auth.username + "/playlists/" + playlist_id + "/tracks", "post", 201, json=data, headers=headers)
return playlist_id
```